# Could not find storyboard error

Tags: xcode, swift

I have been having a number of issues that I have been gradually resolving, however I have encountered an error that I cannot figure out the solution to. When I try to run my app, I am getting the error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle  (loaded)'

The storyboard is definitely named Main.storyboard. If anyone has any ideas, they would be very much appreciated. I am running Xcode 6 beta 3 by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Losing storyboard could be because you changed the name of the app, some linkages etc.
You can try a few things:

- 'clean' the build from Product > Clean, then try running again
- Go into project settings General tab and unset/reset the Main Interface to Main again
- remove the Main.storyboard from the project hierarchy and re-add it again (be sure to set it as Main Interface afterwards though)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately it didn't solve my issue. When I go to select the Main Interface to be 'Main' it doesn't show up in the drop down menu, I have to type it in manually. Is this normal? Also I have been having issues with the info.plist and it looks like some things have been messed up. The executable file is named '${EXECUTABLE_NAME}', bundle identifier 'Andrew-Walker.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}' and bundle name '${PRODUCT_NAME}'. I'm not sure if that is relevant but I thought it might be worth mentioning just in case.

Comment: If Main doesn't show up in the drop menu, something's not connecting properly. Have you tried the 3rd step above for certain?

Comment: Ah! Thank you! I hadn't removed it properly the first time I tried it but this time it's fixed. 

Can I also just check, rather than asking a separate question - The info in the info.plist file was messed up when I updated to beta 3 and I am not sure what each thing was set to. Does it matter what I have for the executable file, bundle identifier or bundle name? Will these affect anything?

Comment: Glad to help! Unfortunately I'm not 100% sure how the entries in the info.plist file will affect your executable. I think the plist is related to your app settings, so maybe it's worth double-checking that to make sure you have all your build targets, linkages, and special permissions set correctly there.